# Rails Polymorphic Voting Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app there will be many things that `users` can vote up or down (in a Reddit like manner).  This will include an upvote/downvote structure for `jokes`, `recipes`, `rules`, etc.  Right now I am trying to set up a polymorphic `votes` using the `joke` model as an example.

I have added `votes` as a polymorphic variable, as can be seen in my `schema`:

```
create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "value"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "voteable_id"
    t.string   "voteable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "votes", ["user_id"], name: "index_votes_on_user_id"
  add_index "votes", ["voteable_type", "voteable_id"], name: "index_votes_on_voteable_type_and_voteable_id"
```

And I added a `float` column to my `jokes` table for `rank`.

I created a `vote` model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  after_save :update_vote

  private
  def update_joke
    vote.update_rank
  end
end
```

And made the appropriate updates to my `joke` model:

```
class Joke < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope { order('rank DESC')}
  def up_votes
    votes.where(value: 1).count
  end
  def down_votes
    votes.where(value: -1).count
  end
  def points
    votes.sum(:value)
  end
  def update_rank
    new_rank = points
    update_attribute(:rank, new_rank)
  end
end
```

And my `user` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :jokes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I have a `votes_controller` as follows:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def up_vote
    update_vote(1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def down_vote
    update_vote(-1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
  def update_vote(new_value)
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:joke_id])
    @vote = @joke.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first

    if @vote
      @vote.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
    else
      @vote = current_user.votes.create(value: new_value, joke: @joke)
    end
  end
end
```

And finally this `_voter.html.erb` partial:

```
<div class="text-center col-xs-1">
  <% if current_user %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", joke_up_vote_path(joke), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="width: 100%"><h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= joke.points %></strong></h3></div>
  <% if current_user %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", joke_up_vote_path(joke), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Is shown on my `otherjokes/kids.html.erb` page:

```
<% @jokes.each do |joke| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% if joke.approved == true && joke.kids == true %>

    <%= render partial: 'votes/voter', locals: { joke: joke } %>

    <div class="col-xs-11"> <!-- non vote container -->

      <h2 id="joke-title" style="margin-top: 0px">
        <%= joke.title %>
        <% if joke.kids == true %>
          <%= image_tag 'icon_kids.jpg', style: "height: 25px; margin-left: 10px" %>
        <% end %>
        <% if joke.mixed == true %>
          <%= image_tag 'icon_mixed.jpg', style: "height: 25px; margin-left: 10px" %>
        <% end %>
      </h2>

      <p id="joke-body"><%= joke.body %></p>
      <p><strong>Submitted by: <%= joke.user.first_name %></strong></p>
      <% if current_user && (current_user == joke.user || current_user.admin) %>
        <%= link_to edit_joke_path(joke) do %>
          <span style="color: blue" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span><span style="color: blue">Edit Joke</span>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to joke_path(joke), data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete Joke
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div> <!-- non vote container -->
  </div> <!-- joke row -->
  <% end %>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <hr style="width: 50%; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px">
  </div> <!-- row -->

<% end %>
```

I have made the following adjustments to my `routes` as well:

```
  resources :jokes do
    patch :approve, on: :member
    patch :reject, on: :member
    post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
    post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
  end
```

Right now when I try to vote on a joke, I get `unknown attribute 'joke' for Vote.` called on the `@vote = current_user.votes.create(value: new_value, joke: @joke)` line at the end of my `votes_controller`.

I would love to get this system running in a way that it could be applied to other future models that will require voting and also (if possible) to do it "the Ruby way".  Can anyone help me structure this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, `joke` is not an attribute of `Vote`. Because it is a polymorphic association you gave it the generic name `votable`. Use this to create a `Vote` for a `Joke`.

```
@vote = current_user.votes.create(value: new_value, votable: @joke)
```

`votable_id` and `votable_type` will be derived automatically by the framework.

Comment: Does that go in the `jokes_controller` or `votes_controller`?  If I put it in the index acton of the jokes controller I get an error on that line saying `undefined local variable or method 'new_value' for #<JokesController:0x007fb99f5adf88>`

Comment: It's the replacement for the nearly identical line in your votes_controller. It's the line that faised the error.

Comment: That changed the error to `undefined method 'update_vote' for #<Vote:0x007fb99b654a08>`.

Comment: I guess it's because you call `after_save :update_vote` in `Vote`. This methods does indeed not exist in `Vote`.

Comment: Isn't `update_vote` defined in the private methods of the `vote_controller`?

Comment: @Liz you also have a filter in your `vote.rb` `after_save :update_vote`, it went through the `VotesController#update_vote`, but you created a new `vote`, so it triggered on the model one which wasn't defined in the model file

Comment: @lusketeer thank you!  Removing the `after_save` method in my `vote.rb` model made the error go away!